# Can I use half float in vertex position vector in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, precision

I'm try to gain performance by saving data volume. Can I use half-float vertex position in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS? If it is not supported, what options do I have?

Comment: Before you spend a lot of time attempting this, are you sure that geometry size is your bottleneck? Also, I know there wasn't a performance advantage in using fixed point values on iOS, despite them being smaller, so that might also apply here. From the OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS: "Avoid using the OpenGL ES GL_FIXED data type. It requires the same amount of memory as GL_FLOAT, but provides a smaller range of values. All iOS devices support hardware floating-point units, so floating point values can be processed more quickly."

Comment: @BradLarson Well... I'm making kind of framework. If it's possible, I want to add half-float feature. I agree that this could be an prematured-optimization, axis of evil :) but I just want to know possibility of this by standard or extension. And `GL_FIXED` is NOT half-float. It's fixed-point real. Half-float means 16-bit float.

Comment: Right, my point was that the PowerVR GPUs are tuned for floating point inputs, and half floats may not gain you anything, just as fixed point doesn't. I've even heard reports that half float textures are incredibly slow on these devices right now.

Comment: @BradLarson That's true half-float won't save operation cost, but it still saves storage cost, and memory bandwidth. But, if the GPU can't handle non-single-float type internally, these savings looks meaningless. Because they will convert everything to single float.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but beware the loss of precision.

- ´highp´ stores a IEEE 754 32bit value.
- ´mediump´ stores number in the range of [-65520, 65520].
- and ´lowp´ in the range [-2, 2)

  So anything else than ´highp´ will probably cause distortion.

Comment: How should I set vertex attribute type?